# Calling from a MySQL/PHP array multiple times in a page

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm probably asking a very simple question here - I know the basics of calling an array but I think I'm probably not doing it in the most efficient way... I'm calling some data into an array at the start of my page and then I want to be able to use this data-set multiple times throughout the page without wrapping everything in PHP if possible.

At present I'm doing it like this -

A variable ('video') is passed to my page through the URL which I get like so:

```
<?php 

$video = $_GET['video'];

?>
```

My `<title>` tag is pulled from the selected database (also titled 'video')

```
<?php
$title = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video WHERE ID = '{$video}'") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_real_escape_string($video);
    while($head = mysql_fetch_array( $title )) { 
    echo "{$head['title']} - BY XXXXX</title>";
            echo "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"{$head['title']} - BY XXXX\"/>";
    }
?>
```

I then want to use the `{$video}` data later on the same page, but defining a slightly different variable like so:

```
<?php
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video WHERE ID = '{$video}' ORDER BY added DESC") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_real_escape_string($video);
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) if ($info['ytembed'] == 'yes')  { 
echo "{$info['embedcode']}";
echo "<div class=\"videobox1\">";
echo "<div class='video-title'>{$info['title']}</div>";
echo "<div class='video-subtitle'>{$info['subtitle']}</div>";
echo "<div class='video-credits'>{$info['cast']}</div>";
echo "<div class='back'><a href=\"./\">&laquo;back</a></div></div>";
} else {
echo "no embed code";
}
?>
```

So at the moment every time I want to pull from that data I'm calling the whole array again - it would be amazing if instead of doing this I could just print/echo selected items

Is there a way to make my code more efficient and do this?

I'm also looking to Validate the ID and if it doesn't exist within the video DB send the user to a 404 page - but perhaps that's a separate question.

Comment: All code in single file right?

Comment: yeap, all in a single PHP page - just split up in different areas (some in the `<head>` some in the `<body>` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello this is refined code

**Replace first 1 with this**.

```
$video = $_GET['video'];
$video = mysql_real_escape_string($video);
$videodata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM video WHERE ID = '{$video}' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

// execute the query and check if video id exist or not 
if(mysql_num_rows($videodata) == 0){
    // 404 redirect code. 
}
```

**Replace Second with**

```
$videodataArray = array(); // created array for storing video data
while ($head = mysql_fetch_array($videodata))
{
    $videodataArray = $head ;  // store the value in video data array for to use in fulll page
    echo "{$videodataArray['title']} - BY XXXXX</title>";
    echo "<meta property=\"og:title\" content=\"{$videodataArray['title']} - BY XXXX\"/>";
}
```

**Replace last one with**

```
    echo "{$videodataArray['embedcode']}";
    echo "<div class=\"videobox1\">";
    echo "<div class='video-title'>{$videodataArray['title']}</div>";
    echo "<div class='video-subtitle'>{$videodataArray['subtitle']}</div>";
    echo "<div class='video-credits'>{$videodataArray['cast']}</div>";
    echo "<div class='back'><a href=\"./\">&laquo;back</a></div></div>";
```

Comment: Just given that a go and it seems to have broken the page: http://www.jameshenry.info/test/video.php?video=14

For reference the existing code (as above) is here:http://www.jameshenry.info/video.php?video=14

Comment: Sorry please change `$videodataArray = array` to `$videodataArray = array()`

Comment: amazing! Working perfectly now - would it be possible for you to give a quick breakdown of what the code is doing?